# Misordered find query on mongo DB native javascript driver leads to degraded short-circuit evaluation performance

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I encountered a problem on MongoDB javascript native driver.

When I use the $and operator, the evaluation order is not as the same as I expected, even if I explicitly specify it.

The $and evaluation order is important because I have one filter which is easy to evaluate, and another much more difficult to evaluate, I want the easier one to be executed first to narrow down the search.

Consider the query below:

```
collection.find({
    c: false,
    $or: [{ a: "1" }, { b: "1" }],
});
```

when I call explain():

```
        "parsedQuery": {
        "$and": [
            {
                "$or": [
                    {
                        "a": {
                            "$eq": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "b": {
                            "$eq": "1"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": {
                    "$eq": false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I wanted the {c: false} filter to be executed first, but { $or: [{ a: "1" }, { b: "1" }]} is executed first instead.

I think this is because javascript dictionary doesn't preserve order, so I tried the second time to explicitly give it an array under the $and operator:

```
collection.find({
    $and: [{ c: false }, { $or: [{ a: "1" }, { b: "1" }] }],
});
```

and call explain():

```
        "parsedQuery": {
        "$and": [
            {
                "$or": [
                    {
                        "a": {
                            "$eq": "1"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "b": {
                            "$eq": "1"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": {
                    "$eq": false
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

The result is the same, {c: false} is still evaluated after {$or: [{ a: "1" }, { b: "1" }]}

I tried to input my query directly into Mongo Compass and it doesn't have this problem. So I guess it's the MongoDB javascript driver doing this rearrangement.

Any idea on this issue?

Comment: Seems relevant: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-13309

Comment: Yep, it seems they don't think it's an issue. Maybe I must find some wordaround.